# What version of curl supports SHA2

Tags: curl

Hello does anybody know as of which version curl supports SHA2? Specifically I'd like to know if version curl-7.16.4 has SHA2 support. Thanks.

Comment: A case-insensitive search for SHA2 in the source code of that CURL version did not turn up any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that curl does not support/implement SSL directly, it does so through the underlying SSL library which, in my case, is openSSL 0.9.7.d. Therefore the question comes down to whether openSSL 0.9.7d suports SHA2 which it does NOT.