# What version of wget supports SHA2

Tags: ssl, wget, x509, sha, sha2

I could not find any detailed information, about what is the minimum wget version to access/verify SHA2 certificates.
I found a very similar question at [What version of curl supports SHA2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466875/what-version-of-curl-supports-sha2) - where the solution seems to be it depends on the used openssl version.

Is it the same with wget? If yes, SHA2 / SHA256 should work from OpenSSL 0.9.8o on.

Does anyone have detailed information about that? Any pointer about where to verify this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I found out, it really depends on the used openssl version.
Check with:

```
    $ ldd $(which wget)
    ...
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb76d3000)
    ...
```

And with your openssl version

```
    $ openssl version
    OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```